# Is there an algorithm for determining whether an expression involving nested radicals is rational?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, algorithms

Specifically, consider expressions involving integers, addition, multiplication, division, and nth roots for any positive integer n. Is there an algorithm that can determine whether such an expression is a rational number? If the expression is a rational number, is it possible to determine which rational number (e.g. test whether an expression is 0?

I've seen papers on denesting radicals, but I couldn't find anything on testing for rationality.

Comment: Beware that formally speaking, the question is ambiguous for such an expression as $\sqrt{7+\sqrt{4}}$. Indeed $\sqrt{4}$ might mean both $2$ and $-2$. Possibly you only allow only positive radicals, which removes the ambiguity, but restricts the scope since in this way you for instance miss roots of totally real cubic (irreducible rational) polynomials.

Comment: I know nothing but http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/number_fields/sage/rings/qqbar.html says "Converting from either AA or QQbar to ZZ or QQ succeeds only if the number actually is an integer or rational."; though I don't know if that means it is guaranteed to succeed if it IS rational.

Comment: @YCor: Are you sure? As far as I know, for a positive real number $x$ the expression $\sqrt{x}$ denotes the *positive* square root, the negative one being denoted by $-\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi I wrote explicitly "formally speaking", and also explicitly mentioned that one can interpret radicals using positivity. As far as I know, the Cardan formulas for roots of cubic polynomials use radical signs for complex numbers.

Comment: @YCor: yes, but over $\mathbb{C}$ the square root is not a well-defined function because there are monodromy issues. Over $\mathbb{R}$ there is a well-defined positive branch. I am pretty sure that writing $\sqrt{4}$ one usually intends $2$. Anyway, this is just a matter of notation.

Comment: Yes I know, the point of my comment is to request clarification, since the OP was sloppy about this point. My example was here to illustrate the difficulties occurring if radicals are not properly defined (as they are not only used for positive numbers), even if the example with square root of a positive number is a bit caricatural.

Comment: By the way, Wikipedia is quite confusing too (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number#Numbers_defined_by_radicals)): they define number definable by radicals saying one uses radicals of positive numbers, and then says "*there are algebraic numbers that cannot be obtained in this manner. These numbers are roots of polynomials of degree 5 or higher*". This is false as they appear as soon as degree 3 then.

Comment: Yes, apparently Wikipedia article is confusing "definible by radicals" and "definible by real radicals", right?

Comment: @YCor The Wikipedia article *doesn’t* restrict the radicals to positive numbers. The only occurrence of the word *positive* in the definition refers to the degree of the root. There is, however, an obvious typo in that it speaks of *integer* additions, subtractions, etc. I’ll fix that.

Comment: [@YCor](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344478/is-there-an-algorithm-for-determining-whether-an-expression-involving-nested-rad#comment861523_344478), perhaps a reasonable interpretation is:  can the radicals be interpreted in some fashion that makes the resulting expression rational?  Of course, only @‍Jim can indicate if this is what was meant ….

Comment: Here is an ambiguous example with complex numbers: $i+\sqrt{2i}$

Comment: Does "Post it on MSE with the question 'Is this rational?'." meet your definition of "algorithm"?

Comment: People talk here about adjunction and are fully correct. I, however, have a lingering suspicion you could do something with continued fractions. Rational numbers have finite continued fraction expansion, irrational numbers have only an infinite representation as a continued fraction, as proved by Euler. Nice 16th century maths!

Answer (score 21):

I'm assuming that you stay within the field of real numbers. You can represent an algebraic real number $\alpha$ by its minimal polynomial $P_\alpha$ plus an additional data, such as the position of $\alpha$ in the set of real roots of $P_\alpha$ (I think there are more efficient encodings). In any case, the main point is that all the usual operations on real algebraic numbers, including real radicals, can be performed *exactly* using the previous description. In particular, given an expression involving nested real radicals, you can compute its minimal polynomial, and then just need to look whether this polynomial has degree 1.

One reference is the book of Bochnak, Coste and Roy, *Real algebraic geometry* (there may be other but I don't know them). The procedure I outlined here is a very special case of quantifier elimination over real closed fields (for the field of real algebraic numbers).

Comment: To quote from http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/number_fields/sage/rings/qqbar.html "minpoly() Compute the minimal polynomial of this algebraic number." so I guess AA implements this functionality.

Comment: @VilleSalo I didn't know this package. Do you know if this implementation allows to convert a nested expression into an absolute expression (meaning an irreducible polynomial plus a sufficiently precise approximation of the root)? Moreover, the doc says that conversion works *only if* the number is rational, and it's not clear to me whether they mean "is" or " is represented as".

Comment: My experience is that it is pretty much an implementation of algebraic reals in both a very correct, and a very practical sense. But I have not studied its theory or exact promises, and have only done simple things with it (computing exact trajectories for some toral automorphisms). (So the answer to your question would be "is", is my best guess.)

Comment: Let me retract that after reading "Algebraic numbers exist in one of the following forms". Any experts on CAS present?

Comment: I see -- that's good to know in any case. The doc gives the example of the computation of the regular 34-gon, and they say that comparing the two algebraic numbers "is currently infinitely long". I don't know whether this means that the algorithm fails in this case.

Comment: Ok. Maybe I need to tone down my love for this package.

Answer (score 12):

One possible algorithm (I fear that terribly slow) would be to produce all algebraic conjugates of your expression (substituting in every possible way each radical by all it's conjugates) and finding the polynomial $\prod (x-\alpha)$ were the product is extended to all the conjugates of your number. By the symmetric function theorem this should give a polynomial with rational coefficients and then you can find it's rational and real roots and check numerically if your expression is nearest to one of the rational roots than to any other root.

On the other hand in Cohen's Computational algebraic Number theory section 2.7.4, there is a very nice algorithm that can be used to find the minimal polynomial of an real or complex number $\alpha$, grossly simplified it finds the LLL-reduction of the matrix:
 $$ \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&\dots &0\\ 0 &1&\dots& 0\\ \vdots& & \ddots &\vdots\\ 0&0&\dots&1\\ \sqrt{N}\alpha^{n-1} & \sqrt{N}\alpha^{n-2}&\dots& \sqrt{N} \end{pmatrix} $$
For a suitable $N$ where $n$ is an upper bound of the expected degree of the relation. Usually the first column will give you a relation of the $\alpha^i$ with reasonably small coefficients which possibly has $\alpha$ as a root and then you can proceed as before. However I'm not sure if there is any guaranty of finding the poynomial. (This algorithm is implemented in the software Pari-Gp son you can check it downloading the program).

Here is an example taken from a note of Daniel Shanks: Incredible identities ([A](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/12-3/shanks-a.pdf), [B](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/12-3/shanks-b.pdf), [C](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/14-1/letter1.pdf)):

$$ \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{22+2\sqrt{5}} = \sqrt{11+2\sqrt{29}} + \sqrt{16-2\sqrt{29}+2\sqrt{55-10\sqrt{29}}} $$

both sides are equal to 7.381175940895657970987266875465130332 using algdep you find that the minimal polynomial of both sides is probably 
$$x^4-54x^2-40x+269$$
and you can check algebraically that both sides are actually roots of this polynomial.

Comment: Computing a polynomial vanishing at $\alpha$ is possible without too much effort, using resultants for sums/products, and the obvious substition for radicals. Using numerical evaluation as you say, you can even find the minimal polynomial at each step. Actually this method may be the best thing to do *in practice*. (But to be certain we need something like interval arithmetic, at least for the operations of sums/products/radicals.)

Comment: Regarding Pari/GP, I guess that you mean the algdep command, which indeed works well. But since here we only need to guess whether $\alpha$ is rational, we can even use lindep (LLL with 2 vectors)

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault you are right but in the case of value 0 you would use  algdep(0,2) which is not very useful, I have added an example to clarify what I mean

Comment: Why is the case of the value 0 different? In Pari/GP the command for detecting rationality is lindep([1,x]) which is a synonym for algdep(x,1). The case where x is a complex number very close to 0 is not different from the other ones.

Answer (score 9):

If you're only interested in a root of each radical, rather than the unique positive real root or another chosen root, then you only have to keep track at each step of the rational polynomial whose roots are all the possible values of that expression.

In this case, it's probably best to compute it inductively, inside-out. Given polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, we can find polynomials whose roots are the roots of $f$ plus the roots of $g$, the roots of $f$ times the roots of $g$, and so on for the other arithmetic operations. For radicals this process is particularly simply, as we just replace $f(x)$ with $f(x^n)$. At the end you have a rational polynomial and can test for rational roots.

I don't know the best way to compute each step. One possibility is to view it as a matrix problem, forming the companion matrices $M_f, M_g$ to $f$ and $g$, taking $M_f \otimes I + I \otimes M_g$ or $M_f \otimes M_g$, and calculating the characteristic polynomial.

Regardless, because this method involves manipulating polynomials with integer coefficients, it's probably best to handle it by working mod $p$ for many large $p$ and then using the Chinese remainder theorem.

If your expression has a simple form then there are many tricks which you can possibly do to check if it has a rational root. For instance if your whole expression is wrapped in a single radical which is then added, multiplied with, and divided by other numbers, then the final output is rational if and only if this radical is rational, and this radical is rational only if the term inside is rational, potentially  allowing you to prove irrationality by considering only a smaller sub-expression.

Answer (score 7):

An algorithm to check whether an expression $f$ involving nested radicals is 0 may be obtained from a general procedure to check whether a semialgebraic set is non-empty. Indeed, you may introduce new variables, to replace each radical $\sqrt{a}$ (or, in general $a^{1/n_a}$) with $\alpha$, with extra equation $\alpha^2=a$ (or, in more generality, for each $a^{1/n_a}$ the equation will be $\alpha^{n_a}=a$) and inequality $\alpha \geq 0$.
This will convert $f$ into a multivariate polynomial, so you will end up with a system of polynomial equations and inequalities, which you will need to test for a solution (something known to be doable in polynomial time for fixed number of inequalities and variables).

---

EDIT: this way one can also solve the full problem in question, i.e. finding whether $f\in\mathbb{Q}$. To this end, we can, instead of the "converted" as above equation $f=0$ we can consider the equation $f=\alpha_0$, where $\alpha_0$ yet another variable. Then the procedure as above will produce a finite semialgberaic set, defined in terms of the variables $\alpha$ introduced while eliminating radicals, and $\alpha_0$. In particular, it will be possible to construct a univariate polynomial $p\in\mathbb{Z}[\alpha_0]$, so that the value of $f$ is one of the (real) roots of $p$. Thus the linear terms of the factorisation of $p$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ will either produce the rational value of $f$, or indication that it is not rational.

Details of these algorithms may be found in e.g. S.Basu, R.Pollack, M.-F.Roy's book [Algorithms in Real Algebraic Geometry](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/marie-francoise.roy/bpr-ed2-posted1.html).

Comment: Can this procedure be generalized to determine whether the expression is rational (and if so, which rational it is)?

Comment: @TimothyChow - yes, it can do this, see my EDIT above.

Comment: This quantifier elimination over the reals has been implemented in QEPCAD https://www.usna.edu/CS/qepcadweb/B/QEPCAD.html and Redlog http://redlog.eu/

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do so exactly, as long as you can express arbitrary rational numbers exactly.

One way of doing this (though probably not the most efficient one) is to explicitly construct a field extension $E$ (as a rational vector space) through iterative adjoining of roots of equations x^k-a. (This can be done e.g. using resultants, but is hard to get to work efficiently in larger cases.) In this extension you can express the radical expression (or one interpretation of the radical expression) exactly.

Then choose a basis of $E$ that has one rational basis vector (say $1$), then an element of $E$ is rational if its coefficients for all other basis vectors are zero.

To take the famous Daniel Shanks example given by Esteban Crespi, a polynomial for the field $E$ is
$x^8-8x^7-196x^6+1208x^5+8742x^4-43224x^3-41476x^2+227880x+8609$. (I calculated this as iterated extension.)

Now, using GAP (not that it is the best tool for this, but its the one I know), we can construct the extension $E$:

```
gap> pol:=x^8-8*x^7-196*x^6+1208*x^5+8742*x^4-43224*x^3-41476*x^2+227880*x+8609;;
x^8-8*x^7-196*x^6+1208*x^5+8742*x^4-43224*x^3-41476*x^2+227880*x+8609
gap> e:=AlgebraicExtension(Rationals,pol);;
gap> x:=X(e,"x");; # define variable
```

Now we take roots of certain quadratic polynomials to get the various radical expressions (here `a` is a root of the degree 8 polynomial, we work in the basis $1,a,a^2,\ldots$).

```
gap> r5:=RootsOfUPol(x^2-5)[1]; # root 5
-609/61755136*a^7+2095/30877568*a^6+133959/61755136*a^5-26101/30877568*a^4-7625627/61755136*a^3+12216013/30877568*a^2+92459893/61755136*a-67326631/30877568
gap> r29:=RootsOfUPol(x^2-29)[1]; #root 29
20639/111931184*a^7-113083/111931184*a^6-290319/111931184*a^5+13886605/111931184*a^4+206942825/111931184*a^3-340055609/111931184*a^2-1241123913/111931184*a+556675495/111931184
gap> r22:=RootsOfUPol(x^2-(22+2*r5))[1]; # root of expression starting with 22
-312563/1790898944*a^7+843909/895449472*a^6+64760293/1790898944*a^5-101635911/895449472*a^4-3089942017/1790898944*a^3+2366180495/895449472*a^2+18967544655/1790898944*a-3396381133/895449472
gap> r11:=RootsOfUPol(x^2-(11+2*r29))[1]; # root of expression starting with 11
-318289/3581797888*a^7+1674531/3581797888*a^6+66219455/3581797888*a^5-200118013/3581797888*a^4-3175703931/3581797888*a^3+4847083105/3581797888*a^2+19761660493/3581797888*a-15977491783/3581797888
gap> r55:=RootsOfUPol(x^2-(55-10*r29))[1]; # root of expression starting with 55
-587121/3581797888*a^7+2690715/3581797888*a^6+125087039/3581797888*a^5-281976997/3581797888*a^4-6353565723/3581797888*a^3+4276345801/3581797888*a^2+54570779021/3581797888*a-1796485759/3581797888
gap> r16:=RootsOfUPol(x^2-(16-2*r29+2*r55))[1]; # root of expression starting with 16    -342159/3581797888*a^7+1944125/3581797888*a^6+71070753/3581797888*a^5-244253347/3581797888*a^4-3446466469/3581797888*a^3+6034696383/3581797888*a^2+23536102611/3581797888*a-5417921945/3581797888
```

Finally we can calculate left and right side and e.g. subtract.

```
gap> left:=r5+r22;
-20639/111931184*a^7+113083/111931184*a^6+4290319/111931184*a^5-13886605/111931184*a^4-206942825/111931184*a^3+340055609/111931184*a^2+1353055097/111931184*a-668606679/111931184
gap> right:=r11+r16;
-20639/111931184*a^7+113083/111931184*a^6+4290319/111931184*a^5-13886605/111931184*a^4-206942825/111931184*a^3+340055609/111931184*a^2+1353055097/111931184*a-668606679/111931184
gap> left-right;
!0
```

Thu everything works exactly, but even in this tiny example the coefficients are a mess, so this in not something to do by hand.

Comment: How do you know that the elements $r_5,r_{29}...$ you have defined are the positive roots?

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault. I do not (respectively it does not make sense to ask this in this model). For the first two roots I can assume WLOG that they are positive since there are Galois automorphisms. What one could do is to calculate a suitable approximation of the root $a$ and then evaluate each root numerically to check which one is positive.